# What is the Input to the agent in the paper "Model Based Reinforcement Learning for Atari", and why does the world model run at inference time?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, machine-learning, papers, proximal-policy-optimization

I am currently reading the paper [Model based Reinforcement Learning for Atari](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.00374). However, they do not specify what exactly they use as input for the agent. I believe it to be the observation space - meaning the stacked frames. During training time, these would be provided by the world model, while at inference time the real environment would provide them - right? However, they also specify under Section 4 under "Stochastic Models" that this stochastic model - which is part of the world model in a sense as far as i understood - is running at inference time. But this would only make sense if we would use any of the outputs of the world model during that time, which we dont as far as i understood. Could somebody clarify this?